# meteor building failed Cordova app for platform Android: Error code 1 for command:

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, meteor

I'm having difficulty loading meteor cordova app into Android device with Android studio and am getting an error Error:Android Source Generator: [jackpot] AndroidManifest.xml file not found. I was previously able to load app onto ios and Android emulators but not on the actual device. Now when i run meteor build .build --server http://localhost:3000 I'm getting the following error msg. I am looking for a fix.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':packageX86Release'.

  > Failed to add /Users/georgeakinian/Projects/jackpot/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/x86/release/folders/2000/1f/main
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 39.997 secs
   Building Cordova app for Android          |
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Failed to notify build listener.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  => Errors executing Cordova commands:

  While building Cordova app for platform Android:
  Error code 1 for command:
  /Users/georgeakinian/Projects/jackpot/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew with
  args:
  cdvBuildRelease,-b,/Users/georgeakinian/Projects/jackpot/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true

Answer (score 0):

In your project folder, try to remove `.meteor/local/build`, `.meteor/local/cordova-build`, and `.meteor/local/plugin-cache` folders and then try to rebuild.